# Ordering a container on something else than the key

Tags: c++, c++11, containers

I am currently trying to implement a A* algorithm and I've come to a problem :

I want to keep a set of distinct objects, identified by a hash (I've used `boost::hash` and family, but can use anything else) and ordered by a public int value, member of those objects.

The goal is being able to retrieve the smaller object based on the int value in O(1) and guarantee uniqueness in the most efficient manner (hash seemed a good way to achieve that, but i'm open to alternatives). I don't need to iterate over the container if those two conditions are met.

Is there any already present implementation that answer those specifications ? Am I mistaken in my assumptions ? Should I just extend any existing container ?

EDIT :

Apparently unclear on what "smaller based on int value" means. I mean that my object has a public attribute (lets say `score`). For two objects `a` and `b`, `a < b` if and only if `a.score < b.score`.

I want `a` and `b` to be in a container, ordered by `score`. And if I try to insert `c` with `c.hash == a.hash`, I want the insertion to fail.

Comment: How about map or multimap? They are not O(1) but still very fast.

Comment: What's the domain of this `int` value?

Comment: @Satus : maps order its content by key. My key would be the hash, but then I'm not sorted according to the int value.

Comment: @ʎǝɹɟɟɟǝſ: I don't understand your question. It's an heuristic cost, if that answers it.

Comment: use a std::set with a custom comparator (either on the int value only, or on the pair of the int value, and the hashcode. It's not clear if you have not duplicates in terms of int value)

Comment: Not clear what you mean by "smaller object" based on the int value

Comment: @lezebulon : no constraints on the int value, can be anything and can be the same for 2 objects. `std::set` with custom comparator makes me either ignore the hash and so I must compare things when I insert to be sure, or it makes me iterate over the container to find the smaller int value.

Comment: @Maravedis The domain of the `int` value is all possible integer values that that value can assume. An example of a domain for an integer representing hours is the range [0..23]. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_of_a_function) for more info.

Comment: @ʎǝɹɟɟɟǝſ : oh. Then the domain is 0..UINT_MAX, I guess. I don't see why it's important, though. (Yeah, I know I said int value, I just didn't think this one through).

Comment: @Maravedis If the domain was more restricted, you could employ specific performant data structures and algorithms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use a custom comparator and a std::set :

```
#include <set>
#include <string>

struct Object
{
  int value;
  long hash;

  std::string data;

  Object(int value, std::string  data) :
    value(value), data(data)
  {

  }

  bool operator<(const Object& other) const
  {
    return data < other.data;
  }

};

struct ObjComp1
{

  bool operator()(const Object& lhs, const Object& rhs) const
  {
    return lhs.value < rhs.value;
  }

};

struct ObjComp2
{

  bool operator()(const Object& lhs, const Object& rhs) const
  {
    if (lhs.value != rhs.value)
    {
      return lhs.value < rhs.value;
    }

    return lhs < rhs;
  }

};

int main()
{

  Object o1(5, "a");
  Object o2(1, "b");
  Object o3(1, "c");
  Object o4(1, "c");

  std::set<Object, ObjComp1> set;
  set.insert(o1);
  set.insert(o2);
  set.insert(o3);
  set.insert(o4);

  std::set<Object, ObjComp2> set2;
  set2.insert(o1);
  set2.insert(o2);
  set2.insert(o3);
  set2.insert(o4);

    return 0;
}
```

First variant will allow you to only insert o1 and o2, second variant will allow you to insert o1, o2 and o3, as it's not really clear which one you need. The only downside is that you need to code your own operator< for the Object type.

alternatively if you don't want to create a custom operator< for you data type, you can wrap a std::map > but this is less straightforward

Comment: Obj2 seems to cut it, even though I remember trying it and it didn't work like I wanted... I feel stupid but thanks for your time. I'll validate your answer once I've tested it. I'll just use the hash for comparison and not the data as I have somehting more complicated. Thanks again

Comment: cool! just be careful that 2 different objects could have the same hash so I don't know if this would work in 100% of the cases

Comment: I'm fairly safe that 2 datas can't have the same hash, and I'm positive that they can't have the same hash AND the same value. With the comparator of Obj2, it should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

Although `std::priority_queue` is an adapter, its `Container` template parameter has to satisfy `SequenceContainer`, so you can't build one backed by a `std::set`.

It looks like your best option is to maintain both a set and a priority queue, and use the former to control insertion into the latter.  It may be a good idea to encapsulate that into a container-concept class, but you might get away with a couple of methods if your use of it is quite localised.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the stl type `priority_queue`. If your elements are integers then you could do:

```
priority_queue<int> q;
```

Priority queues are internally implemented with heaps, a complete binary tree whose root always is the minimum element of the set. So, you could consult in O(1) by invoking `top()`.

However, as you algorithm progress, you will need extract the items with `pop()`. Since is a binary tree, the extraction takes O(log N), which it is not O(1), but is a very good time and it is guaranteed, by contrast with a expected time, which would be the case for an imperfect hash table .

I do not know a way for maintaining a set and extracting the minimum in O(1).

Comment: Thank for your time !
However, this answers the minimum aspect, but not the uniqueness one (which is why I mentioned sets).
According to [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue), priority_queue poses no condition on insertion.

Comment: @Maravedis: for inserting you use `push()` method.

Comment: The person who made the down vote should explain his reason and show your identity worthy and responsibly. Respectfully, I claim that this opinion is essentially correct, and I wonder what thing he has not understood. A down vote without explanation and anonymous is not constructive, it does not help the spirit of this type of community and ultimately is an action that tends to be coward

Comment: @Irleon : `push()` doesn't cut it. I would have to check if the element already exists in the queue before inserting it, which is really inefficient.

Comment: @Toby has already answered you. You could control and know the inserted elements maintaining another set; your hash table, for example. So you first test if the element has been inserted; if negative, then you insert in the priority queue and in the hash table; otherwise, you ignore it. I think it is efficient: O(1) + O(log N) = O(log N). Anyway if your state space grows very fast, then you could consider another search type; iterative deepening A*, for example